# API to table view, adding numeric values and adding columns, and refreshing table every 10 seconds

Tags: swift, uitableview

So, I have been trying to get data from an API, of a stock market, which I want to be refreshed every 10-15 seconds.
The API is "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries".
I have the name being displayed, but when I have to display "Last" which is a decimal, I am not able to display it here:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for:indexPath)

    let item = self.listData[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = item["MarketName"] as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item["Last"] as? String
    print(self.listData.count)

    return cell
}
```

1. I want to add a column which displays "High", "Low", from the API.
2. I want it to refresh every 10-15 seconds.

I want much more help on this project.
I am a chemical engineer, but wanted to implement my idea and started coding myself.
I would be grateful if you could contact me on my e-mail(siddhantmehandru@gmail.com).
I am ready to compensate for the work as well :)

BTW, here is the full code:

```
import UIKit
var listData = [[String : AnyObject]]()

class DemoJsonTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var listData = [[String : AnyObject]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url:String = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries"

    let urlRequest = URL(string: url)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest!) { (data, response, error) in
        if(error != nil){
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }
        else{
            do{
                var response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
                self.listData = response["result"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }catch let error as NSError{
                print(error)
            }
        }
        }.resume()
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return self.listData.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

   let item = self.listData[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = item["MarketName"] as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item["Last"] as? String
    print(self.listData.count)

    return cell
}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for:indexPath)

    let item = self.listData[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = item["MarketName"] as? String
    let lastValue = item["Last"] as? NSNumber
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = lastValue?.stringValue
    print(self.listData.count)

    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self,   selector: (#selector(self.sendUpdateRequest)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

**Function that will call repeatedly after each 10 sec.**

```
func sendUpdateRequest()
    {
    let url:String = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries"

    let urlRequest = URL(string: url)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest!) { (data, response, error) in
        if(error != nil){
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }
        else{
            do{
                var response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
                self.listData = response["result"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }catch let error as NSError{
                print(error)
            }
        }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Please some help on refreshing every 10 seconds

Comment: You can declare it like this `var timer : Timer? = nil`

Comment: Value of type 'DemoJsonTableViewController' has no member 'sendUpdateRequest'
What should I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the line with:

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(describing: item["Last"] as? Double)
```